# Как прервать ожидание ввода с консоли на Linux в С++?

Tags: c++, linux

Есть два потока. Один поток используют std::getline для ожидания ввода, второй поток(основной) исполняет основное тело программы. Так вот, вопрос. Каким образом можно прервать ожидание ввода с консоли для функции std::getline?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15524122/4827341

Comment: Послать ему сигнал (хоть SIGALRM) вызвав [pthread_kill](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html)? С обычными pthreads (в Си) это точно сработает, а что там в крестовой реализации? Не знаю, пробуйте

Comment: Спасибо за ответ